# Passing custom data from Jersey Filter service to Jersey End-Point service

Tags: java, jersey, jetty, osgi

We are in an OSGI environment using Jetty-Felix HTTP server.

We have a bundle that implements a Jersey Filter service.

Another bundle implemetns a Jersey end-point class.

In the Filter, we set up some custom properties using ContainerRequestContext.setProperty().

My question is how can I have access to those properties from the end-point methods ?

@Context does not seem to give me access to anything we I can get back the properties.

Thanks

Comment: Can you use request attributes instead? One of their purpose is to pass attributes between filters and servlets. I must have a way to access the ServletRequest from both, the Jetty filter and the endpoint.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, in the filter, we use ContainerRequestContext.setProperty(key, value);

In the end-point, we can retrieve it with value = HttpServletRequest.getAttribute(key);

Then problem I had was that I was trying to inject the @Context as a class instance. But since it is per request, it should be injected as a function parameter instead, like so :

```
@GET
@Path("/something")
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
public AClass getSomething(@Context HttpServletRequest servletRequest) {
   // Retrieve my thing from the filter
   MyThing thing = (MyThing)servletRequest.getAttribute("the-key-to-my-thing");

   return new AClass(mything);
}
```